# RegEx Capture Groups

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a PowerShell tool to manipulate shortcuts, and I am pretty sure this is going to be a lot easier with a RegEx and capture groups. But I am new to capture groups (first success with a rather simple one just weeks ago).

So, given a string like `some text here -file "some path here" potentially some text here`
I want to capture three groups. Everything before the first quote, the contents of the first pair of quotes, and everything after the second quote, which may also contain quotes.
I *THINK* look aheads and look behinds are what I need, to get everything before and after the "within the quotes" capture group. But, given how much RegEx still makes my head spin, I am looking for some verification that is the right approach. Or am I better just capturing the quoted bit, then doing a PowerShell split on the matched quoted string to get what is before and after it?

**EDIT:**

OK, I think I am learning something here. So, I have implemented a variation on what was mentioned here, and expanded a bit. Because I realized that the -file argument only needs quotes if there is a space in the path, so I really need to check for the unquoted condition. When it is unquoted then it's a space after -file that starts the path, but it can be ended either with another space or the end of the string. So, using this

```
'^(.*?)(-file ".*?"|-file .*? )(.*)$'
```

I can capture either condition, as long as there are arguments behind, so the second space is there to delimit the path. But if the string is

```
some text here -file some_path_here
```

it fails, because I am specifically looking for the second space.
So I tried this

```
'^(.*?)(-file ".*?"|-file .*? |-file .*?$)(.*)$'
```

and to my shock it worked, even with the end of string mentioned twice. I just wonder, am I walking into a trap I can't see doing it this way? Or is there a better way, even if this one isn't brought with peril?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It also works for the second scenario. No need to use alternation. Let me know if you would like a detailed explanation of its working.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I would love a detailed explanation. Goal one is function, goal two is understanding WHY it works. ;)

Comment: Of course. Can you first confirm that the second pattern `(^.*?)(?= "|(?<=-file)\s[a-z]) "?([^"\n]+)"?([a-z ]+$)?` works properly for you? :)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I'll test it tonight and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Does the pattern work for you?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Just an FYI, a day late, that yes the new pattern works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
^(.*?)(".*?")(.*)$
```

[Tested here](https://regexr.com/3tvsh)

If you want to exclude the quotes from the second group, simply put them outside the parentheses like this:

```
^(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*)$
```

Comment: Holy cow, I was expecting something complex! Thanks.

Comment: This also matches the quotes.

Comment: Still matches quotes.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness No it doesn't, not in the second group https://regexr.com/3tvst

Comment: I see that on regexr you used the anchors, so perhaps you can update your post with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/8siYB6S1RR) showing groups captured as per example in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern:

```
(^.*?)(?= "|(?<=-file)\s[a-z]) "?([^"\n]+)"?([a-z ]+$)?
```

- `(^.*?)` Capturing group. Assert beginning of line `^`, match anything lazily.
- `(?= "|(?<=-file)\s[a-z])` Positive lookahead for whitespace and `"`, or anything up to text which is preceded by `-file`. Followed by whitespace and alphabetic characters.
- Match whitespace.
- `"` Match `"` optionally.
- `([^"\n]+)"?` Capturing group. Match anything other than `"` or newline `\n`. Match a `"` optionally.
- `([a-z ]+$)?` Optional capturing group. Match lower case letters or whitespace until end of line `$`.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rt9esy/1).

---

In **Powershell**:

- For the first string:

`$matches = 'some text here -file "some path here" potentially some text here' | Select-String -Pattern '(^.*?)(?= "|(?<=-file)\s[a-z]) "?([^"\n]+
)"?([a-z ]+$)?'`

Then execute:

```
$matches.Matches.Groups
```

to see the contents of all groups.
You can then access contents of captured groups with index. For example:

```
$matches.Matches.Groups[1]
```

Prints:

```
Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 0
Length   : 20
Value    : some text here -file
```

---

- For the second string:

`$matches = 'some text here -file some_path_here' | Select-String -Pattern 
'(^.*?)(?= "|(?<=-file)\s[a-z]) "?([^"\n]+)"?([a-z ]+$)?'`

Command:

```
$matches.Matches.Groups[1]
```

Prints:

```
Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 0
Length   : 20
Value    : some text here -file
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use lookaheads at all. All you need is the following:

```
^(.+)"(.+)"(.*)$
```

You can see a [working example on regexr](https://regexr.com/3tvsq).

## First group

```
(.+)
```

This will match 1 or more characters up to the second group.

## Second group

```
"(.+)"
```

This will match a quote, then one or more characters, then a quote.

## Third group

```
(.*)
```

This will match any amount of characters but it optional, as `*` will match 0 or more characters.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Spotted that and fixed it just now.

Comment: This also matches the quotes.

Comment: Your regex is also terribly inefficient. The combination `.*` is real evil here. You really should use anchors.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Fixed the capturing of quotes.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness + included anchors.